# Where should I map my local workspace when using Team Foundation Server with Git?

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio wants to map my local workspace to C:\Users\localUser\Source\Workspaces\Workspace.  Is there any need to change this mapping if I use Git and I store my local repositories in c:\Repos.. ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your question?  You ask about "mapping your local workspace", which is a decidedly TFVC concept.  But you say that you're running Git, so it's unclear how these two systems interact.  (git-tf?  git-tfs?  Actual Git?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you mean where you are storing your "clone" repositories. If this is the case then no, it does not matter where it is stored on your local disc.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a workspace in Git. When you're using a TFS-hosted Git repo instead of TFVC, you use it **exactly** the same way you'd normally use Git. Put the repo wherever you want.